# I've just ejected expo react native app. How do I run the app via xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, expo, xcode6

newbie here.
I've just ejected my expo app so I now have ios and android folders in my react native directory.
I have run the following snippet `cd ios && pod install`
My question is, what next?
I have this xcode windows but I have no idea what to do:
[image]

The steps I'm meant to follow are below, HOWEVER I don't even know how to open the project on xcode.

````
- Go to "Capabilities"
- enable BackgroundMode.
- Checked into "Background fetch" && "Remote notifications"```

Can someone please guide me for getting started with xcode?
Thanks!
````

Comment: i could not figure out what the exact question is.  are you trying to build react project with Xcode or something else ?

Comment: I'm just trying to run the react native app on a simulator via xcode @zeytin

Answer (score 0):

First of all download dependencies

After Xcode → Preferences → Components → Install iOS simulator

And Run the project.

Comment: https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/homebrew
https://codingislove.com/top-15-react-native-libraries/

Comment: How do I run the project? That's my questions

Comment: command+r is to refresh the app. My question is How to run the app in the first place.